# Random Variable with p.d.f. as product of two $1d$ Gaussians?

Tags: probability-distributions

$X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^{2}_1)$

$X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^{2}_2)$

What random variable as function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ has p.d.f. which is equal to product of two Gaussians?

Comment: If the means are $0$, the distribution of a product of two Gaussians is called *product normal*. You are interested in a more general situation. There is a literature. Searching under product normal should reach some of it.

Comment: I am not sure what the OP means.

Comment: I tried to search in google I received something like this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html . But it is p.d.f. of X1*X2 with zero mean....And I' m interesting not in distribution of multiplication of two r.v., but in expression for r.v., s.t. it's p.d.f. is expressed as multiplication

Comment: @wolfies: Nor am I. Clarification would be useful.